# deploy next.js to amplify using yarn

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

amplify.yaml

```
version: 1
frontend:
phases:
    preBuild:
    commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
    commands:
        - yarn run build
artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
    - '**/*'
cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/**/*
```

I am trying to deploy my next.js application aws amplify.
I am using yarn instead of npm

Build is success. but it says

```
This dev.polyverse.app page can’t be foundNo web page was found for the web address:
https://dev.polyverse.app/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used `yarn` in the local project. AWS Amplify prefers you to use `npm` when you are deploying the project. So you can use `yarn` locally when you are developing it and when you are deploying it to AWS, use `npm` instead of `yarn`.

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. You need to use `npm`

Comment: What is the difference to the already existing answer?